# Setting up cookie

Tags: android, httpcookie, android-cookiemanager

```
try {
    CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
    CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();


    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("user", username);

    URL url = new URL("http://host.example.com");
    cookieJar.add(url.toURI(), cookie);
    System.out.println("Added cookie using cookie handler");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to set cookie using CookieHandler");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How will I add time for the cookie to expire because right now it is more like a session cookie. It expires every time the application is destroyed/closed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `java.net.HttpCookie`, there is a [`setMaxAge(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html#setMaxAge(long)) that sets the expiration of a cookie.